# any information about UMVUE of $θ$ in $0<θ<1,P(x=−1)=θ,P(x∈\{0,1,2,3,⋯\})=(1−θ)^{2}θ^{x} $

Tags: probability, statistics, variance, density-function, parameter-estimation

I was in class and our professor talked about UMVUEs and said this problem is open. I searched for books and papers about this problem but I could not find anything. I search for it in "Theory of Point Estimation E.L. Lehmann" but there was not any useful data.

I searched and find this paper, [On the Nile Problem by Sir Ronald Fisher](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1302.0924.pdf), which seems related. can you help me with references?

Comment: https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cites=9287879967517215212&as_sdt=2005&sciodt=0,5&hl=en has over 100 citations of Fisher's original paper while https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cites=12647558237833230770&as_sdt=2005&sciodt=0,5&hl=en has rather fewer of the paper you link to

Comment: @Henry thank you very much ,the question i asked is still open? is it related to the paper that i linked?

Comment: This is related to the linked paper in the sense that it discusses existence of UMVUE in the absence of a complete sufficient statistic.

Comment: Similar: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4305971/321264.